# I'm trying to pull a random word from a string. Java

Tags: java, string, random

I was given the assignment to pull a random word from a string. All the words have the same letters. The tools that I have gathered so far are: primative data types, and their methods. So far I have:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class HolyCow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String threeLetterWords = "cat nat bat sat fat ";
        String newString = new String(threeLetterWords);
        int newStringLength = newString.length();
        int firstWord = newString.indexOf("cat ");
        int secondWord = newString.indexOf("nat ");
        int thirdWord = newString.indexOf("bat ");
        int fourthWord = newString.indexOf("sat ");
        int fifthWord = newString.indexOf("fat ");
        Random randomWord = new Random();
        System.out.print("Printing a random substring: " 
                + randomWord.nextInt(0 (newStringLength / 4)));

    }

}
```

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are you sharing your answer with us or is there a question cleverly disguised in there?

Comment: Am I on the right path, or should I use substrings instead?

Comment: why not just use split and you'll get an array of strings which you can randomly index

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for reference.

Answer (score 3):

This is much cleaner way of doing it. Your method is also good but this one is clear and easy to understand

```
public class HolyCow {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            String threeLetterWords = "cat nat bat sat fat ";
            String [] arr = threeLetterWords.split(" ");
            Random randomWord = new Random();
            System.out.print("Printing a random substring: " + arr[randomWord.nextInt(arr.length)]);

        }    
    }
```